# Finding the probability from a Poisson distribution.

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

The number of visitors in a museum  during a fixed time interval follows a Poisson distribution. 
Assume that the mean rate of visitors is 2 per minute. 
Find the probability that there will be exactly 20 visitors in the next 5 minutes.
What I did was first to calculate the mean rate for every 5 minutes which gives me the following:
mean rate for every 5 minutes = (2/min) x 5 min = 10

$$P(X=20)= e^{-10}\frac{10^{20}}{20!}
$$
I am not 100% certain if my solution is correct, so can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is correct. The standard formula gives us that the probability of $k$ events in an interval in which there are $\lambda$ events on average is
$$
P(X=k)= e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^k}{k!}.$$
In your case, since you have an average of $2$ visitors per minute, we can conclude that you will have $2\cdot5=10$ visitors on average in any $5$ minute interval.  So, using $\lambda=10$ and $k=20$, we have that the probability of exactly $20$ visitors in a $5$ minute period is
$$
P(X=20) = e^{-10} \frac{10^{20}}{20!} \approx 0.0018660... .$$